# Geometric interpretation of the roots of $\left(\frac{z-1}{1+i}\right)^{4} = -1+i$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, complex-numbers, roots, roots-of-unity

I have this complex equation:
$$\left(\frac{z-1}{1+i}\right)^{4} = -1+i$$

I solved this problem [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2782824/409) using the approach I duplicate below. Is there any geometric way to get the roots? Or is there a more intuitive way to get the roots? Because what I did was through the formula. I would like to understand the concept geometrically.

---

Here's my work from the previous answer:

Working on that equation I get to:
$$(z-1)^4=(1+i)^4(1-i)=-4+4i.$$

To get the four roots of this equation I do the following:

Being $w = z +1.$ I used the formula $w^n = r^n [\cos (an) + i \sin(an)];$

$a = a'/n + k*2π/n,$ with $0 ≤ k < n$ and $r = r'(\frac 1 n)$

then $w_k = r (\cos(a) + i \sin (a)$

In this case $r' = 4\sqrt 2$ then $r = (4\sqrt 2)^{1/4}$ and $a' = 2π - \arctan(4/4) = 7*π/4$

$w_0 = r ( \cos (7*π/16) + i \sin (7*π/16) )$

$w_1 = r ( \cos (15*π/16) + i \sin (15*π/16) )$

$w_2 = r ( \cos (23*π/16) + i \sin (23*π/16) )$

$w_3 = r (\cos (31*π/16) + i \sin(31*π/16) )$

Finally the $4$ fourth roots are: $z_k = w_k + 1, 0 ≤ k < n$

Comment: What do you mean by "geometric way?"

Comment: Looks like you flipped a sign near the beginning.

Comment: @MarkViola I mean that if the solutions correspond to the vertices a regular polygon as it happens with the nth roots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complex roots have a very nice geometric intepretation, the complex $n$ [**roots of unity**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RootofUnity.html) indeed form a regular polygon with  $n$ sides and each vertex lies on the unit circle.

Then in your case we are looking for $w^4=-4+4i=4\sqrt 2e^{i\frac34\pi}$ then the roots you have found form the vertices of a square which lie on a circle with radius $(4\sqrt 2)^\frac14$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for answering! Is there any way to get to that graph (the circumscript square) without going through the development I did to find the roots?

Comment: @Ayesca Of course the knoledgment of that fact is very important to guide the calculation of the roots and can also simplify the derivation. Indeed once we find one root, that is $w_1=(4\sqrt 2)^\frac14 e^{i\frac34\pi}$, we know that the othes three are rotated of 90° starting from that, then for example we know that $w_3=-w_1$. The exponential form is very useful in this case to handle this kind of calculations.

Comment: Again, thank you very much! I'm going to work to better understand the concept of exponentially form.

Comment: @Ayesca The key point is Euler's identity $e^{i\theta}=\cos \theta + i \sin \theta$ then we are allowed to convert trigonometric form $z=r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$ in exponential form $z=re^{i\theta}$ and make the operation using all exponential properties, which are very simple to handle for multiplication and roots.

Comment: Hello and sorry for ask here again but I was making this exercise again and was a problem with the exponential form. How you found θ? For example, in your comment, how did you found θ=3π/4?

Comment: @Ayesca we have $x=-4$ and $y=4$ then the angle in polar coordinates is $\theta=3\pi/4$.